# React Native SafeAreaView BackgroundImage ?

Tags: react-native

Can't find any documentation to implement a BackgroundImage with SafeAreaView.

It seems it's possible: https://blog.callstack.io/react-native-meets-iphonex-a0f5034f7a41

Comment: Please add the code

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how the code structure looks but on a general scenario you can put SafeAreaView inside BackgroundImage to achieve the requirement